# How can I temporarily cover up a bathroom door to a shower room?

Tags: concrete

We are having a local swim meet and we need to temporarily cover the doors to the shower/bathroom on the pool deck to keep parents and others from coming on deck.  The doorway is concrete block structure, with one side of the opening being one concrete block thick and the other side being a flat concrete wall on the inside. I thought of covering with a sheet of plywood, but i think that would require putting in concrete screws and i would rather not put permanent holes in the concrete walls.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a door in the doorway?  If so, what type of handles does it have?

Comment: Do the kids still need to go through (back and forth)?

Comment: I would go with a piece of string or ribbon across the door way and a sign telling people not to go through. How could this possibly require plywood or another permanent installation?

Answer (score 2):

You could try installing two expandable shower rods across the doorway. One should be shoulder high the other knee high. Mount some hooks on to a sheet of plywood. Hang the plywood on the shower rods by the hooks. Or just hang a shower curtain on the rod and place a do not enter sign in front of the entrance. This method may keep you out of trouble with the local fire department as blocking an entrance/exit is generally frowned upon.